# I use Video.get in the youtubesearchpython library, but an Invalid status code error occurs

Tags: python, discord, youtube, bots

I'm doing a code review of a Discord bot, and I used the youtubesearchpython library. However, an error keeps occurring in the Video.get function. Below is the example code. It doesn't work even in the example code. What's the reason?

```
from youtubesearchpython import *

video =Video.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0GKGpObgPY', mode = 
ResultMode.json, get_upload_date=True)
print(video)
```

I've only checked exception handling and searched through Google, but I haven't been able to find an answer yet.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with you.
I tried checking again and replacing it using the getInfo function.

Let's use the solution:

```
videoInfo = Video.getInfo('https://youtu.be/z0GKGpObgPY', mode = ResultMode.json)
print(videoInfo)
```

Link [pypi/youtube-search-python](https://pypi.org/project/youtube-search-python/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35807596)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35807596)

Comment: Hi @CPlus,
I think you should check it carefully when evaluating it.
The link I provided is almost the home page. If the link is broken, it means this question cannot be resolved.

Comment: @NôngMinh But is this intended as an answer to the question? If so, please [edit] to clarify how this solves the problem. Otherwise, please delete this answer.